# Why isn't the "this" keyword working in this constructor?

Tags: java, this

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when I build, I get the error:

> Cannot find symbol

for both of these statements. Here is the constructor.

```
public Course
{ 
    public Course(String cName,String cNum,ArrayList<Module> mod)
    {                         
       this.cName = cName;
       courseNum = cNum;
       this.mod = mod;                     
    }
}
```

Is this what I have to do? If so, why not just forgo the "this" keyword and just use cName = cName? What purpose does the "this" have?

```
public course
{
    String cName;
    public Course(String cName)
    {
        this.cName = cName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well first of all, `public Course { }` is not proper syntax. Should be `public class Course { }`. I highly recommend viewing some Java tutorials online

Comment: and the constructor name has to match the class name, including how it is capitalized.

Comment: Considering you are super new to java, I would suggest reading books or tutorials rather than asking random questions. Because there will be lots and lots of unnecessary discussions. Something like - http://www.onlineprogrammingbooks.com/object-oriented-programming-using-java/

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers! I'm sorry this was a duplicate. I had searched quite a bit but found nothing that quite answered my questions. Also, I'm very sorry for any mistakes I may have made, I'm new to all of this and am working through the tours still! Thanks very much to everyone for your very prompt help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example does not work because the fields you are trying to assign, `cName`, `courseNum`, and `mod`, are not declared in the class. You need to declare the fields in order for the assignments to work. Make the variables private to make sure that they are well encapsulated:

```
public Course {
    private String cName;
    public Course(String cName) {
        this.cName = cName;
    }
}
```

The reason you need to use `this` is to *disambiguate* between `cName`-the-parameter and `cName`-the-instance-variable. You could disambiguate in some other way - for example, by renaming one of the variables:

```
public Course {
    private String cName;
    public Course(String name) {
        cName = name; // Using "this" is no longer required,
                      // because names are different.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue of having two variables of the same name in the same scope. The most local one shadows/hides the other one, and `this.` is needed to reach out to the hidden variable.

> why not just forgo the "this" keyword and just use `cName = cName`?

That wouldn't do anything. Just assign `cName` to itself. Helpful compiler may give you a warning.

Whereas what you really want is to assign the local variable (method argument) to the instance variable (field). Since the two unfortunately have the same name (outside of a constructor that would be considered a style issue), you have to disambiguate by saying `this.cName` if you want to instance variable.

Note that it works without `this` for your second variable, where the parameter and field have different names:

```
courseNum = cNum; // no this
```

Answer (score -1):

The variables prefixed by `this.` will reference the instance variables for the class.  `this.cName = cName` will assign the value for the `cName` variable declared in the constructor's argument list to the `cName` class member variable.

If you just write `cName = cName`, it won't do anything because you're assigning the value of the variable declared in your constructor to itself.

Answer (score -1):

Your second code example is the correct way to format your code. To answer your question, the `this` keyword helps to clarify scope (only accesses an object's instance fields).

Using

```
public course
{
String cName;
    public Course(String cName)
   {
    cName = cName;
    }
}
```

only assigns the parameter value back to itself, while using

```
public course
{
String cName;
public Course(String cName)
{
    this.cName = cName;
}
}
```

assigns the value `cName` from the constructor parameter to the `cName` declared as a class level field.

Answer (score -2):

This should work,

```
public clcass Course
{ 
   String cName,courseNum; // instance variables
   ArrayList<Module> mod;  //// instance variable
   public Course(String cName,String cNum,ArrayList<Module> mod)
   {                         
      this.cName = cName;
      courseNum = cNum;
      this.mod = mod;                     
   }
}
```

Whenever you have the instance variable name same as the parameter name in the constructor ,you need a way to distinguish between the two. `this` keyword helps in this case. Eg - When you say `this.cName` in your constructor it refers to the instance variable `cName` and when you just say `cName` in your constructor it refers to the parameter name of your constructor.